# Some addresses are not shown on android map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

Why getLocationFromAddress return 0 rezults for some addresses

**Ex : 1460 NW Gilman Blvd (Starbucks) Issaquah, WA 98027 .**.

If I introduce this in maps.google I receive the point , but on phone no .

I mention that in general for other addresses it works in 95% cases. This is exmaple when it does not work . Even if i remove what is in () i have  0 rezults .

```
   LatLng addressPoint = MapUtils.getLocationFromAddress(address, this);


public static LatLng getLocationFromAddress(String strAddress, Context ctx) {

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(ctx);

    List<Address> address;
    LatLng p1 = null;

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
        if (address == null || address.size()<1) {
            return null;
        }
        Address location = address.get(0);
        location.getLatitude();
        location.getLongitude();

        p1 = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude() );

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return p1;
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code.

Answer (score 0):

The [Location Address](http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html#fetch-address) section of the Android documentation covers this up.

I cannot confirm if you've already done this, but you'll need an Intent Service to fetch addresses. Once done, define it on the Manifest and from there create the `Geocoder` which calls the necessary methods you'll use.